# Run all files in a directory to measure coverage

Tags: coverage.py

I want to run coverage for all files in a directory.

For instance, I have the following directory structure:

```
root_dir/
    tests/
        test1.py
        test2.py
    code_dir/
```

There are some python files in `tests` directory. I want to run them together using `coverage run` and generate a report.

Individually, I can do like this:

`coverage run tests/test1.py`

`coverage run tests/test2.py`

and generate a report.

How can I do this with a single command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a test runner to find and run those tests.  Either `pytest`, or `python -m unittest discover` will do that for you.

Comment: What if these are not tests? Actually, I have another directory in which I have written benchmarks. I'd also like to run my benchmarks in the same way I ran tests and get the coverage. Any suggestions how this can be done?

Comment: Either write a shell script to run them all, or a Python program to run them all, or structure your benchmarks as pytest tests.

Comment: Thanks Ned Batchelder